# Change Amount Of Columns In Table

Tags: html, layout, html-table

Is it possible to change the amount of columns in this table? I want to remove the blank `td` pair. Also, when I remove the attribute colspan="3", 2/3 of the width of the table is removed. So, what is controlling the amount of columns?

```
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" class="temperature">Temperature</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Temperature:</td>
<td></td>
<td><#temp><#tempunit></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks for your help!

William

Comment: Whata do you mean by amount ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to describe.  Can you elaborate on the problem?

Comment: This happens: https://i.gyazo.com/0a85e9b3a84c9cf5eee4a1510aa216db.png. You can see the white blank cell, but what I can't understand is why that's there and the other two cells on that row haven't widened to cater for it. I tried changing the colspan value to 2 but that didn't work.

Comment: The other question is why do I have to declare the amount of colspans? Surely, the table should widen for the amount of td's there. I tried changing the table-layout value in the CSS file but that just made the problem worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`colspan="3"` is stating that the `td` covers three columns of the table. To remove the blank set of `td`s in the centre of the table, change it to `colspan="2"`. This makes the `td` only cover two columns, so then you can delete the `<td></td>` without having an empty column on the right hand side.

Also, you may want to consider using `th` (Table Header) instead of `td` (Table Data) for the headings. This would mean that you would not need the "temperature" class for styling, as you could use the `th` selector.

Doing both of these things,  this would be your new code:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th colspan="2">Temperature</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Temperature:</td>
<td><#temp><#tempunit></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. Unfortunately, I need the style as the header is styled differently to the rest of the table. This is what it now looks like: https://i.gyazo.com/f58d5ff19dbbe2ff4f4d31c73abba94e.png. So, not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Managed to work it out, thanks for your help.